# Contact block is not mobile responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

```css
.getin {
  background: url("./source/Group.png") no-repeat left;
  background-size: 100%;
  /* background-position: left top; */
  width: 100%;
  height: 439px;
}

.label {
  float: left
}

.span {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* padding: 0 4px 0 6px */
}

.input {
  width: 100%;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, #C4C4C4 90.12%, rgba(196, 196, 196, 0) 100%);
  color: black;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.getinfont {
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 47px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: left;
}

.contbottom {
  margin: 0% 15% 0% 0%;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #333333;
}

.btn-git {
  width: 139px;
  height: 38px;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn-text {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333333;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js">


</head>

<body>

  <div class="Touch_cont row ">
    <div class=" jumbotron getin">
      <!--dock to left side-->

      <!--Dock to right side-->
      <div class="Touch_details col-sm-5 ml-auto">
        <p class="getinfont">We’d love to hear from you!</p>
        <form action="email.php" method="POST" id="GetInTouch_form">


          <div class="contbottom">
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <div class="input-group-prepend ">
                <span id="inputGroup-sizing-default " style="margin:15px 50px -80px 0px">Name:</span>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Default" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span id="inputGroup-sizing-default" style="margin:15px 13px -80px  0px">Company:</span>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Default" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span id="inputGroup-sizing-default" style="margin:15px 48px -80px  0px">Phone:</span>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Default" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span id="inputGroup-sizing-default" style="margin:15px 8px 0px 0px">Message:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Default" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default">
            </div>




          </div>

          <div class="btn-git contbottom" style="float:right">

            <a href="./contactUs/contactUs.html" class=" btn btn-sm btn-text" s>Submit</a>


          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm not able to make it mobile responsive, please help. Every thing is included in the post, all the code and css bootstrap given.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E6CnzT5yJPC8cbkhz6JMIdHt3cS5DthK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It appears that the bootstrap code you're including is making it responsive. There's a breakpoint at 576px.

Can you be more explicit about what you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

so i make your code for responsive for the mobile device. I changed background-size: cover; and height: 100vh; and also added media query to make the heading text little bit smaller on small device. let me know if you have any question.

```css
 .getin {
  background: url("./source/Group.png") no-repeat left;
  background-size: cover;
  /* background-size: 100%;*/
  /* background-position: left top; */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.label {
  float: left
}

.span {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* padding: 0 4px 0 6px */
}

.input {
  width: 100%;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, #C4C4C4 90.12%, rgba(196, 196, 196, 0) 100%);
  color: black;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.getinfont {
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 47px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: left;
}

.contbottom {
  margin: 0% 15% 0% 0%;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #333333;
}

.btn-git {
  width: 139px;
  height: 38px;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn-text {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333333;
}

@media screen and  (max-width: 576px){
.getinfont {
    font-size: 40px;
}
}/*max-width:576px*/
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js">


</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="Touch_cont row ">
    <div class=" jumbotron getin">
      <!--dock to left side-->

      <!--Dock to right side-->
      <div class="Touch_details col-sm-5 ml-auto">
        <p class="getinfont">We’d love to hear from you!</p>
        <form action="email.php" method="POST" id="GetInTouch_form">


          <div class="contbottom">
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <div class="input-group-prepend ">
                <span id="inputGroup-sizing-default " style="margin:15px 50px -80px 0px">Name:</span>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Default" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span id="inputGroup-sizing-default" style="margin:15px 13px -80px  0px">Company:</span>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Default" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span id="inputGroup-sizing-default" style="margin:15px 48px -80px  0px">Phone:</span>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Default" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span id="inputGroup-sizing-default" style="margin:15px 8px 0px 0px">Message:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Default" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default">
            </div>




          </div>

          <div class="btn-git contbottom" style="float:right">

            <a href="./contactUs/contactUs.html" class=" btn btn-sm btn-text" s>Submit</a>


          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your clarification but I still have one problem. In the case of mobile now it is responsive but the text box is not vertically aligned. As I'm new to web development I'm not able to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: so you wants it to align it on vertically center on mobile devices?

Comment: from here you can learn how to make it Vertically Center. try it yourself first. if you still facing issue i will provide you the code https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-vertically-center-text-with-css.html